# All Internet doesnt work

Tags: 14.04, wireless, virtualbox, internet, wifi-hardware-switch

Ok everything was working perfectly fine. Shortly after attempting a to create a virtual box, and that not working properly, I find to discover that my wifi is switched off. ok so I try to switch it back on, and nothing happens, I try some pings and ifdown to test, and it says I'm not connected to the internet, obviously. Next I try to hook in via Ethernet cable, and I get absolutely no connection. I am running ubuntu 14.04 lts on an HP laptop.

Readout of `ifconfig`

```
lo     Link encap:Local Loopback
       inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
       RX packets:127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
       RX bytes:9121 (9.1 KB) TX bytes:9121 (9.1 KB)
```

and the readout of `iwconfig`

```
eth0   no wireless extensions.

wlan0  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
       Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off
       Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
       Power Management:off

lo     no wireless extensions
```

Upon further investigation the readout of `lspci -n | egrep '0200|0280' | awk '{print$3}'` was:

```
10ec:8136
1814:5390
```

Directing me to: `RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller` made by `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.` and a `RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe` made by `Ralink corp.`

Upon even further investigation the readout of `rfkill list` is:

```
0:  phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: yes
         Hard blocked: yes
1:  hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: yes
```

and after hitting my hard switch (with no change of indication light):

```
0:  phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: yes
         Hard blocked: no
1:  hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

actually I was able to remove the soft block with `rfkill unblock 0` but when the readouts all say no it still doesn't work.

So Basically I'm going to try a fresh install and see if it's fixed

Ok at some point something made the Ethernet cable work but wifi is still down.

**It's Fixed, the problem was not with ubuntu it was more with my modem, all is good now.**

Comment: I used to have a similar issue with my wifi and I thought only restarting the computer would solve it. In my case, I eventually found the command `sudo service network-manager restart` to get my wifi up and running again, and  it works every time for me.

Comment: I tried that earlier, I read it in an earlier thread, it doesn't help. I've also tried a full restarting about 3 times mainly via the terminal.

Comment: Try `sudo dhclient eth0` via terminal. Let see..

Comment: `sudo dhclient eth0` returns `RTNETLINK answeres: File exists`

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was more so with the modem, I had to reboot everything, and Re-enable networking and forget all previous connections.